# What statistical methods to use for analysis of a scenario questionnaire?

Tags: anova, spss

I've produced a questionnaire with 3 parts, demographics, attitude questions, and then a final section on particular scenarios. I'm looking to analysis people's response to the scenarios - as in what factors affected their choices.

I've used Likert scales and also categorical - however, I've been using SPSS so have arranged Labels to Values so that data is nominal.

I've used Chi-square tests in contingency tables to look what relationships between answers, and was thinking of using the Kuskal-Wallis test - however, I have thought about factor analysis. I'm not sure what is right or suits my data though!

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

R

Comment: Welcome to the site, @user21859. I don't really follow your question. Could you perhaps state it succinctly at the end?

Comment: What is your research question? Don't analyze the data just because they are available; you can get seriously lost. If you let the data and different statistical methods drag you around, you'd be used instead of a user.